# Amazon Athena: Query to find out patients with compliance=0 for consecutive 10 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

[image: Format of table]

Find all patients having compliance=0 from past consecutive 10 days from current date using Amazon Athena.

```
patient id    compliance      create_date
1               0              2021-01-01
1               0              2021-01-02
1               0              2021-01-03
1               0              2021-01-04--rejected not for consecutive 10 
2               0              2021-01-01
2               0              2021-01-02
2               0              2021-01-03
2               0              2021-01-04
2               0              2021-01-05
2               0              2021-01-06
2               0              2021-01-07
2               0              2021-01-08
2               0              2021-01-09
2               0              2021-01-10-- accepted as for 10 consective
```

Comment: Hello @user8132207 and welcome to stackoverflow! Please check out the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation. Please show us what you have tried so far and update your question to show us specifically what you're struggling with.

Comment: select patient_vertex_id, create_date, compliance from (
    select patient_vertex_id, create_date, compliance, count(*) over (partition by patient_vertex_id) cnt from (
        select *, rn - row_number() over (order by create_date) patient_vertex_id from (
            select *,
                   case when (compliance = '0') or (lag(compliance) over (order by create_date) = '0' and compliance = '0') then
                   row_number() over (order by create_date) end rn
            from patient_adherence_view
        ) a where rn is not null
    ) a
) a where cnt = 10;

Comment: Please add that to the post with some explanation of what works and what doesn't - there is a little `Edit` link below it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, and one can be to take the difference between a given date and the next one and check the cumulative sum of last `X` deltas (which is equal to `10` in your case) and the cumulative sum of your compliance integer on that row (which should be strictly equal to `0`):

```
with base as (

   select 
      *, 
      sum(delta) over (partition by patient_id rows between 10 preceding and current row) as cumdelta ,
      sum(compliance) over (partition by patient_id rows between 10 preceding and current row) as cumcompliance
   from (
     select *, if (date_diff('day', date, next_date) is null, 1, date_diff('day', date, next_date)) as delta
        from (
          select 
            patient_id,
            compliance,
            try_cast(date as date) as date,
            lead(date) over (partition by patient_id order by date) as next_date 
          from data
        )
     )
)

select 
   patient_id, 
   compliance, 
   date, 
   case when (cumdelta = 10 and cumcompliance = 0) then 'yes' else null end as validated_compliance
from base
```